# checking if this is a source package ... ERROR

Tags: r, package, r-package, cran, error-checking

Dears, I'm working in an R package and when I check the package with devtools::check, next note and error are arising to windows and Debian systems:

- checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE

Maintainer: ‘name and e-mail’

- checking if this is a source package ... ERROR

Only *source* packages can be checked.

Can someone answer me how can I solve these two problems?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the "Maintainer:" line in your DESCRIPTION file look like? What exactly is in the package? Do you have just R files or do you have code that needs to be compiled? It's really hard to tell what's going on without any code details.

Comment: It's the output of the package check made by cran. I received this after uploading the package in cran. Apparent, there are errors on Windows and Debian versions, but I don't know as to solve. The complete message can be view in                   
https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/psmMULTI_0.1.0_20200824_155555/Windows/00check.log

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error (the message "Only source packages can be checked"). Check if there is a field "Built" at the end of your Description file. If you have that field, delete it and  build the  .tar.gz  again. I do not why but it worked for me

ana

Comment: Hi, Ana. Thank you for the answer. In my description file there is not this field. I really don't know why this is happening.